# Password hash check

Tags: php, html

I am checking the hash returned from the database with the password placed in the input like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="senhaatual" id="senhaatual"  placeholder="Senha Atual" required="" />
```

PHP:

```
$senhaatual = $_POST["senhaatual"];
$hash = $_SESSION['hash'];
password_verify($senhaatual, $hash)
```

I set the password the same as the hash inserted in the database and it always returns this:

> bool(false)

But it shouldn't be because they are the same. Can anyone explain what might be going on?

Comment: 1) Why is the hashed password in the session? That should never happen. Get it from the database at the moment you need it, not beforehand. 2) What exactly do you mean by `I set the password the same as the hash`. You don't type in the hash into your input, you type in the original password. PHP then hashes your input and compares it to the stored hash.

Comment: @ADyson Yes the hash is in the session, I already checked it. Yes, I type the original password in the input.
It should be true, but it always says that they are different.

Comment: `Yes the hash is in the session`...yes but for security reasons it should not be! My point was that you need to redesign that, the code should just fetch the hash from the database immediately before you need to verify it. It should not store it in the session from some previous query.

Comment: `it always says that they are different` ... well I don't know your password, I don't know what the hash looks like, and I don't know how the password was hashed originally. I don't have any of the information necessary to be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @ADyson Ok, I got it. I will already make this change to the hash query and remove it from the session. Ok, I got it. I will already make this change to the hash query and remove it from the session. The password is originally encoded by wordpress, here is an example hash: `$P$B0.t22GSsgCi/Qt17h5MBVx7jwHGVi/`

Comment: `The password is originally encoded by wordpress` ...and what algorithm did wordpress use to hash it? That's the important thing to know. If it wasn't hashed using PHP's password_hash() function then it's unlikely that password_verify() will be able to test it properly, since it will use password_hash() to hash the input password. If the original password was hashed using a different function and/or algorithm then they won't match.

Comment: @ADyson I tried to look for the algorithm that wordpress uses and I couldn't find it, I got the idea that it used `password_hash ($senhanova, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` or something created by them

Comment: `I got the idea` ...how did you come to that conclusion then, considering you've just said you couldn't find the information?

Comment: @ADyson From what I read and researched on the internet. But I say that I got an idea of ​​this, because I never found anything that even said what was the algorithm that wordpress uses. But I may be wrong. The amazing thing is that the code was working well and from one moment to the next this problem arose in the verification of the hash with the current password field

Comment: Well that kind of thing doesn't just happen by itself. Something must have changed. Do you keep a record of changes to your application? Or did something change on the wordpress side? (It wasn't clear if these are passwords from a still-running wordpress app or you've extracted them from an old database or something?)

Comment: According to https://betterstudio.com/blog/wordpress-md5-encrypt/#:~:text=Nowadays%2C%20WordPress%20uses%20a%20combination,to%20the%20latest%20security%20improvements. (which is from 2019) by default wordpress uses a combination of md5 and phppass to hash. Older wordpress used just md5, which is now obsolete.

Comment: @ADyson Nothing has changed on the wordpress side. Passwords were created directly in wordpress. The only change I made was on the html side of the inputs, but I have already reset it. I was placing the inputs mandatory fields, it was from that moment that it stopped working

Comment: That sounds like a coincidence. Making the field mandatory on the browser side would not change how PHP behaves. Especially if you've reverted the change and still have the issue. Probably something else changed too.

Comment: @ADyson In the new passwords that I am entering in the database I am inserting with this hash `$passwordfinal = password_hash($senhanova, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`. The problem is in checking the hash with the password, but I still haven't figured out the reason

Comment: Right so the issue is with checking new passwords, or the wordpress-generated passwords? Or both? Now it's unclear

Comment: @ADyson At this moment it is with the passwords generated with wordpress. I will test changing the password with the hash I put above to see if it works later.

Comment: You should definitely check that. If you can make that work, then most likely the issue is that the wordpress passwords were not hashed using password_hash. Until you find out what they _were_ hashed with, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @ADyson With the hash generated in the new password in this way `password_hash ($senhanova, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` already works, it is true. So the problem is only with the hash generated by wordpress

Comment: Most likely then it was hashed using a totally different algorithm, as the article I linked to suggests

Comment: @ADyson And is there no way to resolve this situation?

Comment: Hashes are not reversible, so no. If you find out how it was hashed then you can find out how to verify it. You'd then need to put code in your app to do the verification o that, as well as a way of identifying which users should have their password verified using which algorithm. Short of that, I suggest getting all those users to reset their passwords, so you can hash them with the password_hash function - that's quite a common thing to do when applications move to a newer platform with more secure password storage.

Comment: @ADyson Okay, but just a question. I read that the most secure hash currently is the one I'm using `password_hash ($senhanova, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`. Is that information correct or is there an even safer one than the one I'm using?

Comment: Any of the algorithms listed in the options in the documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) should be sufficiently secure for this task.